# How to redirect to another page using an event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, event-receivers, redirect

I want to redirect to another page after an item is added to the list. I have referred many links and found the same alternative that is

```
      SPUtility.Redirect("https://www.google.co.in/", Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPRedirectFlags.Default, context);
```

But this does not work for me. What can I do to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately redirecting after an item is added isn't easy.

The event receivers only allow redirecting when it's a Pre event like ItemAdding by the use of [SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408258%28v=office.14%29.aspx), but this cancels the adding of the item.

So in order to redirect when the add is done you have to:

1. Implement your logic in ItemAdding
2. Retrieve all the values from SPItemEventProperties.AfterProperties
3. Disable Events by setting SPEventReceiverBase.EventFiringEnabled
4. Add the item using code
5. Set SPItemEventProperties.RedirectUrl
6. Set SPItemEventProperties.Status to CancelWithRedirectUrl

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
```

Answer (score 2):

While @alexander and @per-jakobsen have the correct answers I would like to add an alternative approach, the hackish one:

```
private readonly HttpContext _context;

public YourEvent()
{
    _context = HttpContext.Current;
}

public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    _context.Response.Status = "302 Moved Temporary";
    _context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://google.com");
}
```

Note `_context.Response.Redirec(..)` will not work, and this method might not work in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: The value of HttpContext.Current obtained is always null and this causes exception. How can I get the context in an event receiver?

Comment: SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Yes I am working in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution does not work in 2013. It might work for other events though, such as _FieldUpdating_. I believe this is because the context has already changed when the *ing-methods are called (already in some .svc).